# React - How to write keyboard only apps like netflix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events, redux

**Backstory**

I'm new to react (and redux) and want to write a webapp where interaction happens by keyboard/remote events only (arrow keys instead of mouse or touch), similar to what netflix is doing in their embedded TV Apps.

I have a rough idea of how to structure such an app but am not sure if there's a more elegant way to do this in ReactJS.

**Idea for handling the arrow key interaction inside a component matrix**

My idea is to give a component some kind of *focused* state inside a container:

- There is only ever one *focused* component
- *focused* component gets all the keyboard events passed to it by it's container
- container can consume a keyboard event before it reaches the *focused* component
- container itself is activated by routing
- container handles the *focused* states for its child components
- *focused* component notifies it's parent container if it reached an edge (e.g. press DOWN when in an x-axis list) with which the container can decide what should happen next (e.g. other component gets *focused*)

**Example**

Let there be a fullscreen container component called MyLibrary.
It includes 2 components:

1. Navigation on the left
2. ListView of data for active navigation on the right

   ```
       |-----------------------|
       |  Nav  |   List        |
       |  -n1  |   1. Miles    |
       |  -n2  |   2. Bill     |
       |  -n3  |   3. Lester   |
       |       |   4. Herbie   |
       |       |   5. McCoy    |
       |_______________________|
   ```

MyLibrary focuses the navigation component on mount, hence UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT gets passed through MyLibrary into Navigation.

DOWN was pressed, so Navigation updates it's own selected entry state.

RIGHT was pressed, but Navigation does not handle this key, so it notifies MyLibrary that it wants to be unfocused because of RIGHT.

MyLibrary now knows by it's configured component matrix, that an unfocus of Navigation component by RIGHT means to focus the ListView.

Navigation gets unfocused, ListView gets focused. Now all keys are passed to ListView.

**Question**

- How should such an interface be implemented into the react system? Mixins? Some kind of UI store in redux? A global singleton module? What is the best practice here?
- Is there a more standard way to solve this usecase?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this.. There's nothing about react / redux that changes the way you would handle this. Just listen to keyboard events in your root component and figure out how the state changes and pass that state along to your children. You could use redux to store your state, but that doesn't change anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For the UI Views and State Representation

you can use an establish routing solution like:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

It keeps your UI in sync with the state(URL, HashLocation or In memory state)

### For hotkey management

I would also go for a well brewed solution like:
https://github.com/Chrisui/react-hotkeys
It gives you a nice a declarative way to handle hotkeys and focus at a layout level.

### Final Words

After all it is just javascript. If you feel like any existing solution is an overkill, feel free to learn the best concepts from these existing ideas and write your own ghetto JS glue to make your own magical potion.